# How to clear Chrome DNS cache now after they changed it?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

They seem to have changed the `chrome://net-internals` page and it doesn't seem to work anymore. I have tried flushing the socket pool too. It works in incognito.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work anymore" This does not tell us much.

Comment: @Moab The page chrome://net-internals/#dns is always empty now. Looks like they moved it.

Answer (score 0):

> The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed. Please use chrome://net-export to save netlogs and the external catapult netlog_viewer to view them.
>
> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am not allowed to embed screenshots. Fail. Bye for now.

Comment: If this is a quote (you used block quote formatting on the text), please [edit] and provide the source {i.e. link}, else your post may be removed.

Comment: @Greenonline The quote is from the `chrome://net-internals` page and the screenshot is of `chrome://net-export`. I'm not sure how it answers the question, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **chrome://net-internals/#dns**

[image]

Comment: seems not to work

Comment: @törzsmókus What doesn't work ? chrome://net-internals/#dns or clearing of the cache ?

Comment: chrome://net-internals/#dns shows a page, but there’s nothing more there than in your screenshot, and the `Clear host cache` button does not do anything

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1424689/clearing-chromes-dns-cache-in-new-update