# How to clear Chrome's DNS cache in new non “net-internals” versions?

Tags: google-chrome, dns

Chrome's update recently removed net-internals

> The net-internals events viewer and related functionality has been removed

So is there any way you can flush your DNS cache with this new update?

Comment: You are still able to flush the DNS cache though CMD, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @[what the]  This option is still there.

Comment: Is there some difference between clearing through the Chrome internal page as opposed to clearing it via CMD `ipconfig /flushdns`?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the only answer at this point since the recent change to Chrome is to clear all your browsing data. If you're like me this isn't a good option. I am not finding much else on this other than this thread with no answers on Google support. We probably need to upvote this issue more for Google to recognize that this is a problem.

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2361319?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can turn networking off and on again, which triggers a Chrome cache update. In Ubuntu one can use nmcli:

```
nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on
```

Another option is to set the Chrome startup options to "continue where I left off" and restart it. This is an inelegant overkill solution and might have other undesirable side effects, but it *does* clear the DNS cache (at least on Linux). From the Linux command line:

```
pkill chrome
google-chrome >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to clear *all* of your browsing data. It looks like clearing "Hosted app data" is enough.

1. Go to chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
2. Click over to the "Advanced" tab.
3. Scroll down and check "Hosted app data".
4. Click the "Clear data" button.

The window also has a "Time range" drop down. I'm not sure this matters for DNS cache, or even if Chrome stores a timestamp in its DNS table. I set it to "All time", as I don't know when Chrome resolved the name I needed to remove.

Comment: I don't think that setting has nothing to do with clearing the DNS cache.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan Did you test it? Check the codebase? Are you just guessing because of the name? I tested each item in the advanced tab in the "Clear browsing data" settings. "Hosted app data" cleared the entry, while none of the others did.

But if you have test results that don't align I'd be happy to test again.

Comment: Yes, I tested, doesn't clear DNS cache. The correct setting is at `chrome://net-internals/#dns`